# Seeking regression modeling strategies for predicting prices based on categorical variables (one of which is ordered)

Tags: predictive-models, factor-analysis, data-imputation, regression-strategies

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228507/method-for-predicting-price-based-on-geographical-market-product-and-company), which never received an answer.

Let's say I have widgets that have different quality ratings $q\in\{0,1,\dots,N_q\}$ and which are in different regions $R\in\{R_1,R_2,\dots,R_{N_R}\}$. Suppose that the price of these widgets is based on, in a time-varying manner, both objective quality (for which quality ratings are imperfect proxies) and regional effects. Prices are known to fluctuate a little and offer somewhat noisy signals. Finally, let's say that I have an amazing black-box model for the time-varying prices of medium quality ($q=5$) widgets in $R_{Canada}$ and want to find a simple way to adjust this model to work for different qualities and regions.

In practice it seems that when there is enough data for a given quality/regional pair that a simple multiplicative adjustment is not bad. But how can I impute this adjustment for quality/region pairs for which I don't have much data?

If these were continuous, rather than categorical values, imputation isn't necessary as you could compute the covariance of price on the various variables (perhaps after a transformation) and then back out the multiplicative adjustment based on the Canadian 5-quality model predictions. But here although quality is ordered, region is not. I have heard that factor analysis can be useful here, but I don't have the slightest idea how.

Does anyone have some regression modeling strategies that I might explore here? I've considered hierarchical models as a commentator on the above-linked post considered, but though I think I have used hierarchical models before I don't see how they would extend to this problem.

What strategies might I explore here?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to share information across individual (region,quality) problems.

For example, you could use a multi-task learning framework to couple the individual adjustments (at the quality level) of the Canada-5 model. For each region independently, fit a linear adjustment by minimizing some loss function like this one:
$L_R(\alpha,\beta) = \sum_{q} (\alpha_{q}+\beta_{q} C_5-Y_{q})^2+\lambda \sum_{q>q^\prime}H(\alpha_{q}+\beta_{q} C_5-\alpha_{q^\prime}-\beta_{q^\prime} C_5)$,
where $C_5$ is the output of the Canada-5 model, and $H$ is the hinge-loss function $H(x)=\left\lbrace \begin{array}{cc} -x, & x<0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$

This is just $L_2$ loss with a hinge-loss penalty on different quality models. This would penalize $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s in such a way as to encourage the predictions of higher quality models to be higher than lower quality models in the same region.

---

Another approach is to use transfer learning to train a new model for each (region,quality) pair using the Canada-5 dataset as the source domain. One such method is outlined in [Want et al. (2014). Active learning under Model Shift](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/wangi14.pdf). The model shift method is to

1. Fit a model to predict $y_{source}=f(x_{source})$. (You've done this, it's your Canada-5 model)
2. Apply the model to the target domain to get the offsets $z=y_{target}-f(x_{target})$.
3. Fit another model to the offset $z=g(x_{target})$.
4. Apply the offset model to the source domain to get $\hat{y}_{source}=g(x_{source})+y_{source}$.
5. Train the target domain model on the data set $(x_{target},y_{target})\cup(x_{source},\hat{y}_{source})$.

In the paper, the authors use Gaussian processes to model the offsets and such, but it seems to me the approach will admit other types of models.

---

Both ideas could be combined; one could conceive of a multi-task transfer learning problem.